# How to :server connect to neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, connect, cql

I am starting to learn neo4j graph database. I have installed it and run it on my browser. It is asking me to connect to Neo4j database
[image]

How can i complete this process?

Answer (score 6):

If using the downloaded version, `neo4j`/`neo4j` is the default login/password.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the default username: neo4j, password: neo4j to work on Neo4j Desktop 3.1.4. Since I connected as user neo4j, I suspect my credentials were provided when I signed into neo4j using OAuth (i.e., google or linkedIn credentials). I created a new user and password to access my database with the neo4j Bolt driver (python).

[image]